# android policy phonewindow getSystemService permission denied

Tags: android, onkeydown

I am trying to use

`Context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)`

to get the `topActivity` in `onKeyDown` method of class `phonewindow.java`.But I was told that `"java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks()"`,how can I change the permission or is my code right ?

below is my piece of code

```
protected boolean onKeyDown(int featureId, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   Context mContext;
   mContext = getContext();
   ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   ComponentName mCName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
   String ActivityName = mCName.getClassName().toString();
   Log.d(TAG, "PackageName is " + ActivityName);
   ...
}
```

Comment: kindly post ur persmission? in manifest file

Comment: Do you mean frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes i mean manifest file

Comment: here is the permission of frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml  <permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.APP_INFO"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
        android:label="@string/permlab_getTasks"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_getTasks" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: it does not work ;i think it is not a good idea adding above code in frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml,First,it has the permission GET_TASKS.Second,in PhoneWindowManager.java i have tried the method before,it works,they use the same manifest file

Comment: i think there must be something wrong then try tracing ur project again

Comment: i know how it happened ,every app has a phonewind and the permission is inherited from the app;so if a app  with the GET_TASKS permission is running ,it works ;i should add my code to the system manager level such as PhoneWindowManager.java;anyway ,thank you !